# Does a monotonically increasing function attain a maximum on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$? Prove that it does, or give an example against.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, real-numbers, maxima-minima, monotone-functions

Does a monotonically increasing function attain a maximum on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

I have to either prove that it does, or give an example that shows that it doesnt.

My attempt at it is that since for any $a>b, \Rightarrow f(a) \geq f(b)$, then the function will attain a max, it follows directly that on the interval $[c,d]$ the function will attain its max at $d$.

Is this correct? How can I prove it? Or is it wrong? If so, give an example against it.

Comment: Do you mean a compact subet of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes, maybe I should have mentioned that.

Comment: This is a correct proof if the compact set is an interval. You need a somewhat more sophisticated argument in general. Hint: a compact set is bounded.

Comment: @EthanBolker What does “monotonically increasing” mean if its domain is a general compact topological space?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos In that context it has no meaning, but the OP specifies a compact subset of the real line. Your answer fleshes out my hint.

Answer (score 3):

If $K$ is a non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb R$, then it has a maximum $m$. And, for every $x\in K$, since $x\leqslant m$, $f(x)\leqslant f(m)$. So, the maximum is attained at $m$.

Comment: Thank you! It really is this simple and elegant?

Comment: Yes, it is. $\ddot\smile$